# Unit testing console application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application

I am trying to test my very first console app and while trying to do so I came across the roadblock of not being able to test any negative scenarios.  Here's why - I've separated all user actions into individual methods, and those user actions are dictated by the result of an IF statement which either does or does not meet my conditions.

I can simulate the console input for a positive condition which will then exit my code and complete my test.  But (and obviously so), when I try to test any false condition, the statement restarts and my test is failed with "insufficient memory exception".  What I've been trying to figure out is, is there any way to test my negative conditions?

```
public float UserInput2()
{
    // Ask the user to type the second number.
    Console.WriteLine("Type another number, and then press Enter");
    bool Valid2 = false;
    while (Valid2 == false)
    {
        string Input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Input2);
        if (!float.TryParse(Input2, out Number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, please try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            Valid2 = true;
            num2 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input2);
        }
    }
    return num2;
}


[Test]
public void UserInput2Test()
{
    var calc = new CalculatorApp.Program();
    var output = new StringWriter();
    string expectedresult = (string.Format("Type another number, and then press Enter\r\n5\r\n", Environment.NewLine));
    Console.SetOut(output);
    var input = new StringReader("f5");
    Console.SetIn(input);
    var input2 = new StringReader("5");
    Console.SetIn(input2);

    calc.UserInput2();
    //num1 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(output);

    Assert.That(output.ToString(), Is.EqualTo(expectedresult));

}
```

Comment: This isn't a proper unit test because your test contains a test of your console program. You need to abstract out the core logic of your program into a separate class (outside of it being a console app), with defined inputs / outputs and then unit test that class.

Comment: You cannot unit test your method because it is dependent on the `Console` class. Consider converting your `UserInput2` method signature to `bool TryReadUserInput2(out float value)`, then use the return value of that method to determine whether to write a message to the console.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line:  `num2 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input2);`  You already have the parsed value in your `Number` variable so all you need to do is either `num2 = Number;` or `return Number;`

Comment: @IanKemp Can you give me an example of this?